# bash- Use find, grep, sed, or a mix of either of these to solve this

Tags: bash, shell, find

I am asked to use grep, sed, find, or a mix of either of these to solve the following (I can also use any other bash commands to solve this as well, but I must use at least one of the three mentioned above).

Lets say I have numerous files in my home directory *and sub-directories, and sub-sub-directories, etc* that have the word "draft" in its name. For example, program**Draft**, or **draft**script.c (can be lower or upper case). I have to delete all files with "draft" in its name, and which are a week or more old.

I already have a solution to this that works, but it's a little bit long :

```
find . -mtime +7 | egrep '.*draft.*' | xargs rm
```

I want a more simplified solution but I can't find one. Like, for example, I would like to this using just find, or just grep, etc.

Also, I'm curious if this can be done using find -delete.

For this question though, anything simpler and/or more concise than what I got will serve as an adequate answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU [find](/questions/tagged/find) :

```
find . -type f -mtime +7 -iname '*draft*' -delete
```

or

```
find . -type f -mtime +7 -iname '*draft*' -exec rm {} +
```

The latter one put as many files possible as argument for each `rm` commands

- `-iname` is like `-name` but is case-insensitive

Comment: alternatively `-exec rm {} \;` instead of `-delete`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: The goal here is to be concise as possible

Comment: @sputnick I like this solution a lot, just pointing out alternatives.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: better to use `-exec rm {} +` (with a `+` instead of a `;`) as it makes `find` behave more like `xargs`, grouping files together into a single command invocation.  It is POSIX-standard (for POSIX 2008 or later), unlike `-delete` which is not POSIX-standard.